# Как посчитать O-нотацию в данной функции

Tags: c++

```
void func(int A[], int low, int high)
    {
        int i = low;
        int j = high;
        int x = A[(low + high) / 2];
        do {
            while (A[i]< x)
                ++i;
            while (A[j]> x)
                --j;
            if (i <= j)
            {
                int temp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[j];
                A[j] = temp;
                i++; j--;
            }
        } while (i < j);
        if (low < j) //recursion
            func(A, low, j);
        if (i < high) //recursion
            func(A, i, high);
    }
```

Есть такая функция. Мне нужно посчитать ее О-нотацию. `while (A[i]< x)` -O(n) и `while (A[j]> x)`- O(n). Тоесть О-нотация етих двух циклов O(n). И дальше я думаю што О-нотация цикла `do while`- O(A*N). Вопрос какая О-нотация всей етой функции, я не знаю как рекурсия повлияєт на О-нотацию цикла, и прав ли я вообще c О-нотациями циклов.

Comment: Что такое «онотация»? Сложность что ли?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Да ето сложность

Comment: Вы бы заголовок перевели на русский. И правила форума это требуют, да и количество прочтений (и вероятность ответа) будет сильно меньше, если так оставить (решат, что всё будет непонятно).

Comment: @Сергей ок спасибо

Comment: Поменял также везде вам на "О-нотацию", чтобы не сбивало читающих - в русском она так пишется (предположу, что и в украинском). Я сперва решил, что про аннотацию речь идёт:-)

Comment: @Сергей спасибо

Comment: Для худшего случая время T: `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(0) + O(n) = T(n-1) + O(n)`, т.е. арифметическая прогрессия, `T(n) = O(n^2)`. Для наилучшего `T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + O(n) = O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: @retmas ето  для всей функции O-нотация, я правильно понимаю

Comment: @Oleg, да для всей.

Comment: @retmas большое спасибо

Comment: @retmas скажите пожалуста, а што такое Т і откуда ви его взяли?